# jquery load function doesn't replace previously loaded page

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I am trying to load different pages into div when user clicks on links.

Here is my index.html code:

```
 <li><a href="javascript:loadContent('#content_main','cardinal.jsp')">SMS</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:loadContent('#content_main','paypoint.jsp')">Paypoint</a></li>
```

And loadContent function looks like this:

```
function loadContent(elementSelector, sourceUrl) {
$(""+elementSelector+"").empty();
$(""+elementSelector+"").load("http://localhost:7070/ning/"+sourceUrl+"");
}
```

My cardinal.jsp looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
    alert("Cardinal");
},5000);
});
```

And paypoint.jsp has this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
    alert("paypoint");
},5000);
});
```

I first click the link SMS. This loads the cardinal.jsp and displays the alertbox(cardinal) every 5 seconds. Now, when i click paypoint link, i am supposed to run the paypoint.jsp page only. But, instead, it seems like it appends the paypoint.jsp contents to div (which already has contents of cardinal.jsp). This results in both the alertboxes being displayed alternatively.

As you can see , i have tried to empty the contents of div before loading the new page. But, it still doesn't work. What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interval doesn't disappear if you remove the code that set it. If you want to remove it do something like:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  alert("paypoint");
}, 5000);

clearInterval(interval);
```

Remember that you're not loading a totally new page but new content to existing page.

Comment: It doesn't work. If i give clearInterval, alert boxes are not getting called at all.

Comment: If i call clearInterval, i will not be able to call setInterval again when i click the links again right?

Comment: Yes, you can. I just doubt if your document ready event fires for dynamically added content.

Answer (score 1):

Yes as suggested by Heikki.... this worked for me.....

In index.html

```
<script>
    var interval;
function loadContent(elementSelector, sourceUrl) {
    $(elementSelector).empty(); 
    interval = window.clearInterval(interval);
    $(elementSelector).load("http://localhost/"+sourceUrl+"");
}
</script>
```

and in paypoint.jsp

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    interval = window.setInterval(function(){
    alert("Paypoint");
    },5000);
});
```

and in cardinal.jsp

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    interval = window.setInterval(function(){
    alert("Cardinal");
    },5000);
});
```

check if this works for you as well....